# JSOM: Why web.lists.GetByTitle('myList') does not throw exception while web.Title throw exception

Tags: client-object-model, csom

In JSOM, we can not access a property of an object before load and excecute. 
But I don't understand why **code 1 works** and **code 2 doesn't**:

**Code 1:**
Here I am accessing the List property of web

```
var web= context.web;
var lists=web.get_lists().getByTitle("myList"); //this works.
```

**Code 2:** Here I am accessing the Title property of web

```
var web=context.web;
var title=web.get_title(); //this throw exception
```

Both the code accessing the web properties but one works and other doesn't. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:** made code changes for JSOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Code 1** you have only client side references for server side objects (both the `web` and `lists` variables, the later one is a **single list**, should be called `list`), but you don't read any properties of them. If you would try to get the title of the list (via the get_title() method), you would receive an exception as well, as this property was not yet requested from the server.

The same is true for **Code 2**. In the first line you have no exception, as you ask only for a reference. In the second line you try to access a property, that you have not yet requested, so an exception is thrown.

Comment: So it means when ever I am asking for a reference it wont throw a exception but if I try to read the properties then I will get a exception.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example with  `SP.ListCollection.getByTitle` method you are only getting non-initialized List client object.  In order to retrieve List object properties, the request has to be submitted to the server via `SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync` method as demonstrated below:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
ctx.load(list);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
         console.log(list.get_title());
      },
      function(sender,args){
         console.log(args.get_message());
      }
    );
```

In the second example the situation is similar, before getting client object properties it has to be requested via `SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync` method.
In order to access `Web.Title` property use the following code:

```
var listTitle = list.get_title();
```

Answer (score 0):

SP.Web does not have property "Title". You have to use method get_title() for retrieving it.
See the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee552858(v=office.14).aspx)

```
var value = SP.Web.get_title();
```

Comment: Updated the code